# Maximum and minimum eigenvalues of matrix with variable coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like help to find the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of the following symmetric matrix of order $n$, $A=I_{n}+(p(x)-2)(\xi \otimes \xi )|\xi|^{-2}$.

Where

- $I_{n}$ is the identity matrix of order $n$
- $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
- $p \in C^{1}(B_{1})$
- $\xi \otimes \xi$ is the matrix where the $(i,j)$ element is $(\xi_{i}\xi_{j})$
- $B_{1}$ is unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

I find the minimum eigenvalue is $\min(p(x)-1,1)$ and the maximum eigenvalue is $\max(p(x)-1,1)$, but I would like to know conditions on the function $p$ such that the maximum and minimum values of eigenvalues do **not** depend on the point $x \in B_{1}$.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to obtain the eigenvalues of a matrix which is "updated" by a rank-one matrix.

A particular case is when $p(x)=0$ : in this case we find the matrix of a symmetry with respect to the hyperplane with normal vector $\xi$, therefore with spectrum $-1$ and $1$ (this one with multiplicity $(n-1)$).

In the general case there is a very important formula, which is :

$$\det(M+uv^T)=(1+v^TM^{-1}u) \det(M), \ \ \ u,v \ \  \text{considered as column vectors}\tag{1}$$

(see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)).

A particular case of formula (1) (even if, in fact, you are interested by $\det(A-\lambda I_n)$) applied with $u=(p(t)-1)\dfrac{\xi}{\|\xi\|}$ and $v=\dfrac{\xi}{\|\xi\|}$ gives

$$\det(A)=(1+(p(t)-1))=p(t)$$

You will find in the following article :

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965907000614
a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: The papper shows how to calculate the eigenvalues ​​of matrix $A$, which, in fact, are the ones pointed out in my post and depend continuously on x. My main doubt is whether this dependence on x can be eliminated, that is, there are the highest $\Lambda$ and and lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$ ​​of A, such that $0<\lambda \leq \Lambda$, and $\Lambda,\lambda$ does not depend of $x$.

Comment: I understand now...

Comment: Furthermore, $\det(A)=p(t)-1$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix which you indicated with

$$
P = \xi \otimes \xi / | \xi|^2
$$

Is easily seen to be a rank-one orthogonal projector. Hence its eigenvalues are $(0,1)$.

The eigevalues of $A$ are therefore $(1+p(x)-2,1+0)=( p(x)-1,1)$.

The only possibility to have both the minimum and the maximum be independent of $x$ is that $p(x)$ is independent of $x$.